# Route's with a leading/traling slash and without slashes

Tags: python, flask

Could you please explain to me the diffference between:

```
@app.route( '/something' )
```

compared to:

```
@app.route( 'something/' )
```

and also compared to:

```
@app.route( 'something' )
```

So i can better distinguish them?

Answer (score 2):

In a word, `/foo` was the normal use case, `/foo/` was used when you want to make the URL looks like a path/folder, `foo` was wrong. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

1. The URL rule should start with a slash(`/`).
2. `/foo` and `/foo/` was two different URL rule, see the details in the docs:

> The following two rules differ in their use of a trailing slash.

```
 @app.route('/projects/') 
 def projects():
     return 'The project page'

 @app.route('/about') 
 def about():
     return 'The about page'
```

> The canonical URL for the projects endpoint has a trailing slash. It’s similar to a folder in a file
>   system. If you access the URL without a trailing slash, Flask
>   redirects you to the canonical URL with the trailing slash.
>
> The canonical URL for the about endpoint does not have a trailing
>   slash. It’s similar to the pathname of a file. Accessing the URL with
>   a trailing slash produces a 404 “Not Found” error. This helps keep
>   URLs unique for these resources, which helps search engines avoid
>   indexing the same page twice.

Link: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior

Comment: I'm not sure i have understood when to use one over another. And what if it has no slash at all.

Comment: Just use the one you like and always add a slash before the URL rule.

Comment: If you missing the start slash, Flask will add one for you, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Will do, but i want to understand the difference in all 3 occasions.